# What is an algebra bundle?

Tags: fiber-bundles

If I associate a copy of an algebra with every point on a manifold - such that one could specify a connection between algebras associated with neighboring points - have I specified an algebra bundle?  If the definition of an algebra bundle is more restricted than that, is there a recognized term for what I've described?

Comment: What are neighboring points on a manifold?

Comment: By a neighboring point of p in a topological space, I mean a point that is in every neighboorhood of p (every contiguous open set that includes p).

Comment: In a manifold, the only point in every neighborhood of $p$ is $p$.

Comment: I thought a neighborhood is an open set for which one can move in any direction away from $p$ without leaving the set.  Wouldn't any neighborhood of $p$ need to include other points (you can draw a path through the set that does not terminate at $p$)?

Comment: Yes, it includes other points. But given any point $q$ in the neighborhood other than $p$, there is a neighborhood of $p$ contained in the original neighborhood that doesn't contain $q$.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense.  Rather than a connection between neighboring points, a connection defining how elements of the algebra at $p$ map onto the algebra at another point given a path between the points, which converges to the identity for points and paths within a neighborhood of $p$ as we shrink the neighborhood.  Is that better defined?

Comment: That makes more sense, but usually if we're attaching algebras to a space it would be a sheaf of algebras, which assigns an algebra to each open set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100548/discussion-between-rossng-and-matt-samuel).

Comment: I won't be a very good chat companion, but you can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_%28mathematics%29